# AWS DR : How to know when entire us-east-1 is down

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, health-check

I'm working on into an **DR (Disaster Recovery)** plan and building an architecture within AWS to handle it. I'm facing some challenges in monitoring the architecture.

**Architecture In short :**

> I've **2 EC2** servers running in **2 different regions** and those health are monitored by **Route53 health checks** and I configured Route53 in **failover routing** with **active-passive mode** which will switch the traffic to another region.

> We have this health check to create an **cloud watch alarm** which connects **AWS SNS** to send email when the primary region server is down.

I'm considering an use-case where the entire primary region is down, say **us-east-1** as primary region. The cloud watch is in **us-east-1** region since the **route53 health check** metrics are available only in **us-east-1** region.

When the **us-east-1** region goes down, my application server goes down with the **cloud watch alarm**. Even though Route53 routes the traffic to secondary region I won't able to know there is a failure in primary region since I didn't received mail from **AWS SNS**.

Is there any solution within AWS or outside AWS to know **(alert when traffic routed to secondary region)** when there is an down in my application?

Shouldn't we know when the **Route53** switches the traffic to secondary region when we configured failover routing?

How are all other applications which uses the same architecture knows when the us-east-1 goes down?

Comment: Honestly you will know if us-east-1 is down, because then half the internet stops working, literally. Any other region would be bad enough but us-east-1 in particular would mean that A LOT of things break. I could even imagine Route53 then having big problems... If "only" EC2 is down in us-east-1 then you can still rely on SNS and cloudwatch. If you want a surefire way to be informed you need to use e.g. a different cloud provider or service that explicitly does not run on AWS and monitors your application externally.

Comment: does this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/health-api.html

Comment: Thanks @luk2302. So you mean that i need to emulate the same work of Route53 health check (pinging primary EC2 server) outside of AWS to know us-east-1 is down right.

Comment: I wouldn't bother. But if *you* expect us-east-1 to go down you might need to do a lot of things outside AWS, yes.